# Percolation in a finite, 2D rectangular grid

Tags: probability, percolation

Images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'd like some hints to the ??? pointed out as well as how to approach the case in which the X,Y are opposite corners.

P.S. This is a problem which I came up with after a conversation with a friend. So I do not know what the answer is/whether this is a standard textbook problem. Googling has yielded a somewhat similar paper [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ie960663i). However, there each cell/node has an independent probability of being filled.

Comment: Where are these images taken from?

Comment: They're screenshots from my working notes written in LaTeX as I was trying to think through the problem. At the time, I think I was too lazy to convert all that LaTeX to StackExchange markup, so I pasted images. Unfortunately, I don't think I have the source anymore.

Comment: I see, thanks. (Few more characters)